# Property of the number of such integer matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

Given a positive integer $N$, put
$$
\mathcal{A}=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z} \, , \, ad-bc =4 \, , \, |a|,|b|,|c|,|d| \le N
\right\}
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{B}=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z} \, , \, ad-bc =4 \, , \, |a|,|b|,|c|,|d| \le N \, , \, a,b,c,d \text{ are even}
\right\}
$$

Denote $a=\# \mathcal{A}$ and $b=\# \mathcal{B}$. The question is how to evaluate $a$ and $b$ for given $N$ (just suppose that $N=10000$) and $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{b}{a} = ?$

**My attempt**

I thought that for $\mathcal{B}$ it is equivalent to calculate the number of such integer matrices whose determinant is $1$. And I wanted to use the Smith normal form but I got stuck on how to use the condition of the range of variables.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!